# Дубликаты в XML файле при экспорте

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

**Что получается в ходе экспорта**
**Структура xml файла при экспорте**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CLIENTS>
  <CLIENT>
    <name>Марк</name>
    <surname>Чубенко</surname>
    <lastname>Григорьевич</lastname>
    <login>Mark</login>
    <password>markmark</password>
    <seriaPassport>4242</seriaPassport>
    <numberPassport>424231</numberPassport>
    <deschotel>desc</deschotel>
    <countDaysLive>37</countDaysLive>
    <dateOfBirth>15.11.1999 0:00:00</dateOfBirth>
    <CLIENTS />
    <HOTELROOM>
      <nomer>004</nomer>
      <countPeople>4</countPeople>
      <category>Полулюкс</category>
      <payment>35000</payment>
      <REGHOTELS>
        <startLive>02.04.2020</startLive>
        <endLive>03.04.2020</endLive>
        <desclive>Оплачено</desclive>
      </REGHOTELS>
      <REGHOTELS>
        <startLive>10.04.2020</startLive>
        <endLive>10.04.2020</endLive>
        <desclive>Оплачено</desclive>
      </REGHOTELS>
    </HOTELROOM>
    <HOTELROOM> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
      <nomer>004</nomer> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
      <countPeople>4</countPeople> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
      <category>Полулюкс</category> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
      <payment>35000</payment> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
    </HOTELROOM> <!-- нужно убрать вот это -->
  </CLIENT>
</CLIENTS>
```

**Мой код в C#**

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var clients = context.Clients.ToList();

                int countCBCategory;
                string nomername;

                if (clientid > 0)
                {
                    clients = context.Clients.Where(x => x.idClient == clientid).ToList();
                }

                int key = 0;
                XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("CLIENTS"));
                for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count(); i++)
                {
                    doc.Element("CLIENTS").Add(new XElement("CLIENT",
                        new XElement("name", clients[i].name.Trim()),
                        new XElement("surname", clients[i].surname.Trim()),
                        new XElement("lastname", clients[i].lastname.Trim()),
                        new XElement("login", clients[i].login.Trim()),
                        new XElement("password", clients[i].password.Trim()),
                        new XElement("seriaPassport", clients[i].seriaPassport.Trim()),
                        new XElement("numberPassport", clients[i].numberPassport.Trim()),
                        new XElement("deschotel", clients[i].deschotel.Trim()),
                        new XElement("countDaysLive", clients[i].countDaysLive.ToString().Trim()),
                        new XElement("dateOfBirth", clients[i].dataOfBirth.ToString().Trim()))
                        );

                    var regHotels = context.RegHotels.ToList();

                    foreach(var regHotel in regHotels) 
                    {
                        if (clients[i].idClient == regHotel.idClient) 
                        {
                            var hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.ToList();

                            try
                            {
                                countCBCategory = CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString().Count();
                            }
                            catch (System.NullReferenceException error)
                            {
                                countCBCategory = 0;
                            }

                            if (countCBCategory > 0)
                            {
                                if (TBCount.Text != " ")
                                {

                                    hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.category == CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() && x.idFlat == regHotel.idFlat).ToList();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.category == CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() && x.idFlat == regHotel.idFlat && TBCount.Text == x.countPeople.ToString()).ToList();
                                }
                            };

                            foreach(var hotelRoom in hotelRooms) 
                            {

                                var HotelRoomXML = new XElement("HOTELROOM",
                                    new XElement("nomer", hotelRoom.nomer.Trim()),
                                    new XElement("countPeople", hotelRoom.countPeople.ToString().Trim()),
                                    new XElement("category", hotelRoom.category.Trim()),
                                    new XElement("payment", hotelRoom.payment.ToString().Trim())
                                    );

                                var ourClient = doc.Descendants("CLIENT")
                                .Where(x => x.Element("name")
                                .Value.Equals(clients[i].name.Trim())).FirstOrDefault();

                                nomername = hotelRooms.Select(x => x.nomer).First().Trim().ToString();

                                if(ourClient != null) 
                                {
                                    if (!ourClient.Elements("CLIENTS").Any())
                                        ourClient.Add(new XElement("CLIENTS"));

                                    bool duplicatePatient = false;
                                    foreach (var elem in ourClient.Element("CLIENTS").Elements("HOTELROOM"))
                                    {
                                        duplicatePatient = XNode.DeepEquals(elem, HotelRoomXML);
                                        if (duplicatePatient)
                                            break;
                                    }

                                    if (!duplicatePatient)
                                    {
                                        ourClient.Add(HotelRoomXML);
                                    }
                                }

                                if(clients[i].idClient == regHotel.idClient) 
                                {

                                    var regHotelXml = new XElement("REGHOTELS",
                                        new XElement("startLive", regHotel.startLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Trim()),
                                        new XElement("endLive", regHotel.endLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Trim()),
                                        new XElement("desclive", regHotel.desclive.ToString().Trim())
                                        );

                                    var ourRegHotel = doc.Descendants("CLIENT")
                                        .Where(x => x.Element("name")
                                        .Value.Equals(clients[i].name.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HOTELROOM")
                                        .Where(x => x.Element("nomer")
                                        .Value.Equals(nomername)).FirstOrDefault();

                                    if(ourRegHotel != null) 
                                    {
                                        ourRegHotel.Add(regHotelXml);
                                    }

                                }


                            }

                        }
                    }
                    key++;
                }
                string filePath = @"xml\export.xml";
                doc.Save(filePath);

                MessageBox.Show("Экспорт завершен !");
            }
```

**Класс CLIENT**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CLIENTS")]
    public class CLIENTS
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLIENT")]
        public List<ClientXML> CLIENT { get; set; }
    }
```

**Класс ClientXML**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "CLIENT")]
    public class ClientXML
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "surname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastname")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "login")]
        public string Login { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "seriaPassport")]
        public string SeriaPassport { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "numberPassport")]
        public string NumberPassport { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "deschotel")] 
        public string Deschotel { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "countDaysLive")]
        public string CountDaysLive { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "dateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "REGHOTELS")]
        public List<RegHotelXML> REGHOTELS { get; set; }

    }
```

**Класс HotelRoomXmL**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "HOTELROOM")]
    public class HotelRoomXML
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "nomer")]
        public string Nomer { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "countPeople")]
        public string CountPeople { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "payment")]
        public string Payment { get; set; }

    }
```

**Класс RegHotelXML**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "REGHOTEL")]

    public class RegHotelXML
    {

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "startLive")]
        public DateTime StartLive { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "endLive")]
        public DateTime EndLive { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "desclive")]
        public string Desclive { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Это в отладчике надо отслеживать,  откуда  лишняя запись берется. Смотрю вы потрудились, атрибуты на свойства навесили, все подготовили для сериализации, а затем вручную решили построить xml, почему так?

Comment: @Bulson Я не знаю как по-другому сделать, да в отладчике я нашёл почему он берёт лишний раз, я не доглядел, Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var clients = context.Clients.ToList();

            var wasreg = new List<RegTest>();

            var wasnomer = new List<string>();

            int countCBCategory;
            string nomername = "0";

            if (clientid > 0)
            {
                clients = context.Clients.Where(x => x.idClient == clientid).ToList();
            }

            int key = 0;
            XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("CLIENTS"));
            for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count(); i++)
            {
                wasnomer.Clear();

                doc.Element("CLIENTS").Add(new XElement("CLIENT",
                    new XElement("name", clients[i].name.Trim()),
                    new XElement("surname", clients[i].surname.Trim()),
                    new XElement("lastname", clients[i].lastname.Trim()),
                    new XElement("login", clients[i].login.Trim()),
                    new XElement("password", clients[i].password.Trim()),
                    new XElement("seriaPassport", clients[i].seriaPassport.Trim()),
                    new XElement("numberPassport", clients[i].numberPassport.Trim()),
                    new XElement("deschotel", clients[i].deschotel.Trim()),
                    new XElement("countDaysLive", clients[i].countDaysLive.ToString().Trim()),
                    new XElement("dateOfBirth", clients[i].dataOfBirth.ToString().Trim()))
                    );

                var regHotels = context.RegHotels.ToList();

                foreach(var regHotel in regHotels) 
                {
                    wasreg.Clear();
                    if (clients[i].idClient == regHotel.idClient)
                    {
                        var hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.ToList();


                        if (CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Все")
                        {
                            //hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.category == CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() && x.idFlat == regHotel.idFlat).ToList();
                            hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.category == CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
                        }
                        if (TBCount.Text != "")
                        {
                            //hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.idFlat == regHotel.idFlat && TBCount.Text == x.countPeople.ToString()).ToList();
                            hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => TBCount.Text == x.countPeople.ToString()).ToList();
                        }
                        if (CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() != "Все" && TBCount.Text != "") 
                        {
                            hotelRooms = context.HotelRooms.Where(x => x.category == CBCategory.SelectedItem.ToString() && TBCount.Text == x.countPeople.ToString()).ToList();
                        }

                        foreach(var hotelRoom in hotelRooms) 
                        {
                            bool check = false;

                            foreach(var s in wasnomer) 
                            {
                                if (hotelRoom.nomer.ToString() == s) 
                                {
                                    check = true;   
                                }
                                nomername = hotelRooms.Where(x => x.idFlat == hotelRoom.idFlat).Select(x => x.nomer).First().Trim().ToString();
                            }                               

                            if (check == false)
                            {
                                wasnomer.Add(hotelRoom.nomer);

                                var HotelRoomXML = new XElement("HOTELROOM",
                                    new XElement("nomer", hotelRoom.nomer.Trim()),
                                    new XElement("countPeople", hotelRoom.countPeople.ToString().Trim()),
                                    new XElement("category", hotelRoom.category.Trim()),
                                    new XElement("payment", hotelRoom.payment.ToString().Trim())
                                    );

                                var ourClient = doc.Descendants("CLIENT")
                                .Where(x => x.Element("name")
                                .Value.Equals(clients[i].name.Trim())).FirstOrDefault();

                                nomername = hotelRooms.Where(x => x.idFlat == hotelRoom.idFlat).Select(x => x.nomer).First().Trim().ToString();

                                if (ourClient != null) 
                                {
                                    if (!ourClient.Elements("CLIENTS").Any())
                                        ourClient.Add(new XElement("CLIENTS"));

                                    bool duplicatePatient = false;
                                        foreach (var elem in ourClient.Element("CLIENTS").Elements("HOTELROOM"))
                                        {
                                            duplicatePatient = XNode.DeepEquals(elem, HotelRoomXML);
                                            if (duplicatePatient)
                                                break;
                                        }

                                        if (!duplicatePatient)
                                        {
                                            ourClient.Add(HotelRoomXML);
                                        }
                                }

                            }
                            if (clients[i].idClient == regHotel.idClient) 
                            {
                                bool checkss = false;
                                bool let = false;


                                foreach (var s in wasreg)
                                {
                                    DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(s.StartLive);
                                    DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.Parse(s.EndLive);
                                    string descs = s.Desclive;

                                    int idClientMark = clients[i].idClient;
                                    int idFlatMark = hotelRoom.idFlat;

                                    var querys = context.RegHotels.Where(x => x.idClient == idClientMark && x.idFlat == idFlatMark && x.startLive == dateStart && x.endLive == dateEnd && x.desclive == descs);

                                    if (querys.ToList().Count() < 1)
                                    {
                                        checkss = true;
                                    }

                                    if (s.idClient == clients[i].idClient && s.idFlat == hotelRoom.idFlat && s.StartLive == dateStart.ToString() && s.EndLive == dateEnd.ToString() && s.Desclive == descs)
                                    {
                                        checkss = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                int idClientMark1 = clients[i].idClient;
                                int idFlatMark1 = hotelRoom.idFlat;
                                DateTime dateStart1 = regHotel.startLive;
                                DateTime dateEnd1 = regHotel.endLive;
                                string descs1 = regHotel.desclive;

                                var hotelRoomCheck = context.RegHotels.Where(x => x.idFlat == idFlatMark1 && x.idClient == idClientMark1 && x.startLive == dateStart1 && x.endLive == dateEnd1 && x.desclive == descs1);

                                if (hotelRoomCheck.ToList().Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    let = true;
                                }

                                if (checkss == false && let == true) 
                                {
                                    nomername = hotelRooms.Where(x => x.idFlat == hotelRoom.idFlat).Select(x => x.nomer).First().Trim().ToString();
                                    wasreg.Add(new RegTest(clients[i].idClient, hotelRoom.idFlat, regHotel.startLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), regHotel.endLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), regHotel.desclive));

                                    var regHotelXml = new XElement("REGHOTELS",
                                        new XElement("startLive", regHotel.startLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Trim()),
                                        new XElement("endLive", regHotel.endLive.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy").Trim()),
                                        new XElement("desclive", regHotel.desclive.ToString().Trim())
                                        );

                                    var ourRegHotel = doc.Descendants("CLIENT")
                                        .Where(x => x.Element("name")
                                        .Value.Equals(clients[i].name.Trim())).FirstOrDefault().Descendants("HOTELROOM")
                                        .Where(x => x.Element("nomer")
                                        .Value.Equals(nomername)).FirstOrDefault();

                                    if(ourRegHotel != null) 
                                    {
                                        ourRegHotel.Add(regHotelXml);
                                    }
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
                }
                key++;
            }
            string filePath = @"xml\export.xml";
            doc.Save(filePath);

            MessageBox.Show("Экспорт завершен !");
        }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]